# Layout, where many containers need to take up rest of space but one inner scroll. CSS

Tags: css, layout, scroll, flexbox, containers

I have a problem that I have spent many hours on and could not find a solution in any way. I will link the code in CodePen. It is just a subset of my layout. This is the reason for some of the root element's styling.

I basically have a layout where the page/screen/window should not have a scroll, but the inner body of the table widget should, when there are enough elements that go beyond the expected area of the table.

Basically I have a top content on the page, and a table widget. The table widget is to take up the rest of the space of the screen. The table has a title and a header. The body is to take up the rest of the table space and to have a scroll when it has elements that go beyond that space.

I have searched many resources over stack-overflow and tried many things. I will provide the current state of the layout in the pen. Here you can see all that I think is my best try.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLogbJ

The central area of interest is the .body element. Based on things I've read I have styled it:

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Try creating a div that's going to have the container and apply the `display: flex;` on it, it'll work like a body, taking all the available space, and on the `.body`, change it to `display: block;` and add `position: fixed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `overflow: scroll;` to `.body` and give the `.item` a `min-height`

Also give your `.table` a `max-height: 100%;`

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/metaDesign/ez6L047q/5/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the contents of the area you want to scroll is set to scale to fit it's container. For the internal scroll you are looking for you would need to have:

1. A set height for the container so it won't expand to fit the content (in this case you want it to be 100% of the screen)
2. The content must not scale in height to fit it's container. It has to maintain it's height so that it remain larger than it's container.

If you have those 2 conditions you should find the scroll bars appear.